# geom_col is assigning the wrong independent variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-col

I have a simple two variable data frame with a third variable acting as a factor

```
DF <- data.frame(Depth = c(8.6, 19.6, 42.6, 60.6, 79.4, 101.4, 121.4, 137.6, 163, 180),
       Rb = c(103, 59, 99, 53, 107, 87, 52, 33, 105, 49),
       Litho = as.factor(c(1,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,1,2)))
```

I want to create a bar graph of the absolute values so I am using `geom_col()`. I want to plot Rb as a function of Depth therefore Depth should be the discrete variable. However, when I plot using

```
ggplot (DF, aes(x=Depth, y=Rb))+
geom_col()
```

the graph has horizontal bars that show how much Depth there is at each discrete Rb reading. I want to see the value of Rb at each discrete Depth.
[image]
Reversing the x and y gives the same problem, just with vertical bars

```
ggplot (DF, aes(x=Rb, y=Depth))+
geom_col()
```

[image]
I have also tried the same with `geom_bar(stat = 'identity')`, but it's still the same problem.

**EDIT - THIS WORKS IF ANYONE CAN EXPLAIN WHY**

```
ggplot (DF, aes(x=Depth, y=Rb/10, fill=Litho)) +
geom_bar(stat='identity') +
labs(x="Depth", y="Rb") +
scale_x_continuous (trans = "reverse") +
scale_y_continuous (position = "right") +
coord_flip()
```

For some reason, dividing the Rb values by 10 sorts the problem out?? Dividing by any number greater than 2 works but if you divide by 1 or 2 (Rb, Rb/1, or Rb/2) it groups the data like in the above graphs and the bars are vertical, not horizontal??
[image]
Thanks,
Jeremy

Comment: So you don't want to plot the Depths but 1:15 vs Rb?

Comment: I do want the bars plotted at their respective depths, this graph is just what I could get from LibreOffice; it also uses all 15 datapoints of my full frame....sorry about the confusion. The graph you added below looks great, the bars are all in the correct order, but I would like to have the bars at their correct depths which range from 0 to 30

Comment: Why are the range of depths from 0 to 30? Your lowest values of depth is `8.6`, your highest value `180`. I don't understand where 0 to 30 come from.

Comment: The sample data I put up was only 10 of my 15 points. The actual depths for the 15 points range between 0 and 30 cm (8.6mm, 19.6mm, etc); sorry, I forgot to include units. The 1:15 was just a poor example from LibreOffice. However, I have found a solution (see above) but have no idea why it works. Any thoughts?

Comment: Should work without the division by 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may force the orientation in `geom_col()` with the `"orientation"` argument.

From `?geom_col`:

> `orientation`  The orientation of the layer. The default (`NA`) automatically determines the orientation from the aesthetic mapping. In the rare event that this fails it can be given explicitly by setting `orientation` to either `"x"` or `"y"`.
>
> [`geom_col`] treats each axis differently and, thus, can thus have two orientations. Often the orientation is easy to deduce from a combination of the given mappings and the types of positional scales in use. Thus, ggplot2 will by default try to guess which orientation the layer should have. Under rare circumstances, the orientation is ambiguous and guessing may fail. In that case the orientation can be specified directly using the `orientation` parameter, which can be either `"x"` or `"y"`. The value gives the axis that the geom should run along, `"x"` being the default orientation you would expect for the geom.

See also discussion in the issue [Unexpected (?) orientation with geom_col](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3932).

```
ggplot (DF, aes(x = Depth, y = Rb)) +
  geom_col(orientation = "x")
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to do, thanks @dedmonds! Now, are you able to explain why using y=Rb/10 seemed to force the orientation argument (see the edit to my OP)?

Comment: No, I don't know specifically, but the documentation says when the orientation is not specified the "default (NA) automatically determines the orientation from the aesthetic mapping." Something about the assumptions it makes must change when you give it Rb/10.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your images I tried to build the output you are looking for:

```r
ggplot(DF, aes(x=rank(Depth), y=Rb, fill=Litho)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  labs(x="Depth", y="Rb") + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,15,1), trans = "reverse") +
  scale_y_continuous(position="right") +
  coord_flip(xlim=c(0,15)) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major.x = element_line(colour = "grey50"))
```

results in
[image: Rplot]

Use `scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired") +` for are colour themes given by `RColorBrewer::display.brewer.all()`.

#### One Last Try

I'm just guessing what you really want. A modification to my code shown above

```r
ggplot(DF, aes(x=Depth, y=Rb, fill=Litho)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  labs(x="Depth", y="Rb") + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,200,50), trans = "reverse") +
  scale_y_continuous(position="right") +
  coord_flip(xlim=c(0,200)) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major.x = element_line(colour = "grey50"))
```

Comment: Thanks Martin but this is still the same issue. When you plot this, it is plotting a bar showing the Depth value at discrete Rb values. The plot should have 15 bars at (roughly) evenly spaced intervals (the Depth values) that show me the how much Rb is at each interval

Comment: If you can tell me how to upload pictures from my hard drive (not a link) then I will add some images of how the graph should look

Comment: Press [CTRL] + [G] inside the editor. You can drag an image there.

Comment: Ah that's it. I have added images to the question now

Comment: Sorry for the confusion Martin, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I learnt a lot about ggplot. Hardest part was to understand how the graphic should look like.

Comment: Take a look at how the graph changes when you use y=Rb, y=Rb/1, or y=Rb/2 compared to y=Rb/10 using the final code of yours I put in my edit